# How to make locked cursor click world space canvas button

Tags: unity-game-engine, canvas, cursor

[image]

I have a world space canvas with a button attached (Button4) but I am unable to click it while the cursor is locked.  The only way iv been able to click it is when I unlock the cursor, but that's not a proper solution. Am I doing something wrong with the cursor?

Another approach I tried was to try to raycast using the middle of the screen. Problem with this is I need a collider.  Trying to add a 2D collider was a mess because the text and button canvas follows you as you move so the 2D collider gets messy.  When I tried to add a 3D collider it "worked" but said I was clicking on the parent object (in this case Edwin model).  I couldn't get it to detect I was clicking the actual button.

Any ideas?  Preferably I would like to make the cursor be able to click while its locked.

Comment: well there is no cursor so you cant see where it is, and its in the middle of the screen locked there so it cant move over to the button.  Best way to handle it is on pressing of space or enter or such

Comment: Btw you do not need a collider if you use the [`GraphicRaycaster.Raycast`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.GraphicRaycaster.Raycast.html) (you will find that component on the `Canvas`)